# Change hash-url to hash-bang url using angular4

Tags: node.js, angular, prerender, angular4-router

I am using angulr4  this is my URL http://localhost/#/login.html I want to change this url to http://localhost/#!/login.html. I found solution for angularjs but not for angular4. I am using "Prerender Node" for SEO regarding this is link https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-node

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are after is `APP_BASE_HREF`. In your routing module `app-routing.module.ts` add to your module `providers` array `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '!' }` and import `import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';` at the top of the file. It looks like you are already using `HashLocationStrategy`.

**Example** `app-routing.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404-not-found' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '!' }
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Further reading Angular 4 documentation**

[PathLocationStrategy](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy):

> `PathLocationStrategy` is a `LocationStrategy` used to configure the
>   `Location` service to represent its state in the `path` of the browser's
>   URL.
>
> If you're using `PathLocationStrategy`, you must provide a `APP_BASE_HREF`
>   or add a base element to the document. This URL prefix that will be
>   preserved when generating and recognizing URLs.
>
> For instance, if you provide an `APP_BASE_HREF` of `'/my/app'` and call
>   `location.go('/foo')`, the browser's URL will become
>   `example.com/my/app/foo`.
>
> Similarly, if you add `<base href='/my/app'/>` to the document and call
>   `location.go('/foo')`, the browser's URL will become
>   `example.com/my/app/foo`.

[HashLocationStrategy](https://v4.angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy):

> You can go old-school with the `HashLocationStrategy` by providing the
>   `useHash: true` in an object as the second argument of the
>   `RouterModule.forRoot` in the `AppModule`.

[APP_BASE_HREF](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF):

> ... `APP_BASE_HREF` token represents the base href to be used ...
>    a string representing the URL prefix that should be preserved when generating and recognizing URLs